# Grails: Help with HQL query

Tags: sql, grails, hql, grails-orm

I'm not very good in SQL and HQL...

I have two domains:

```
class Hotel {
 String name
}

class Room {
 Hotel hotel
 float price
}
```

How many hotels have at least one room ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You probably want to make this a bi-directional relationship.

```
class Hotel {
 String name;
 List<Room> rooms;
}

class Room {
 Hotel hotel
 float price
}
```

Then HQL:

```
 from Hotel h where size(h.rooms) >= 1
```

Will return Hotels where the rooms collection has at least one value.

More details [here](http://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/core/3.3/reference/en/html/queryhql.html#queryhql-expressions).

Comment: I know about this way but i can't modify DB structure(domains) at this moment... Maybe in future it will be done in this way but now i can't :(

Comment: Then in plain SQL: select count(*), hotel.name from room join hotel on room.hotel_id = hotel.hotel_id group by hotel.hotel_id having count(*) > 1

Comment: Thx for advises. I've implemented in this way(all fields are not null so every room has a not-null hotel field):

Room.executeQuery("select count(rm) from Room as rm group by rm.hotel")[0]